# Как предсказать временный ряд

Tags: python, машинное-обучение, временные-ряды

Я пытаюсь сделать предсказание временного ряда на несколько дней вперед. Делаю это с помощью SARIMA. Я никогда не работал с временными рядами и у меня возникают сложности.
Это не обязательно должна быть SARIMA.

Тут [датафрэйм](https://disk.yandex.ru/d/iGg3npx0xTsmqg).

В столбце registration- количество регистраций объекта с дискретизацией в час.

[image: Декомпозиция]

Ниже мой код:

```
import warnings
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import statsmodels.api as sm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('fivethirtyeight')

df=pd.read_csv('mt_resample (1).csv',index_col=[0],parse_dates=[0])

train_arima = df["Частота регистраций"]
model_sarima = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(train_arima,
                                order=(1, 1, 1),
                                seasonal_order=(1, 1, 1, 12),
                                enforce_stationarity=False,
                                enforce_invertibility=False)
results_sarima = model_sarima.fit()

# Получаю пердсказания на 100 шагов вперед
pred_uc = results.get_forecast(steps=100)

# Доверительный интервал
pred_ci = pred_uc.conf_int()

ax = y.plot(label='observed', figsize=(20, 15))
pred_uc.predicted_mean.plot(ax=ax, label='Forecast')
ax.fill_between(pred_ci.index,
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 0],
                pred_ci.iloc[:, 1], color='k', alpha=.25)
ax.set_xlabel('Date')
ax.set_ylabel('Registration')

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

[image: Предсказание]

Предсказывает не очень! Подскажите что я делаю не так, и как я могу улучшить результат?

Comment: Ну, с сезонностью у модели явно не задалось. Я не знаю детально, как тут `seasonal_order` настраивать и вообще. Данные явно хорошо завязаны на время в течении дня и, возможно, на день недели (а может и месяца), а для годовых циклов, например, у вас просто недостаточный период данных (меньше года). Нужно либо выделять вручную из даты-времени время дня, день недели и прочие полезные признаки, либо как-то настраивать модель под такую периодичность (я не знаю как). Но вообще нужен анализ, может и это всё не поможет.

Comment: И впредь выкладывайте, пожалуйста, рабочий код. Мне как минимум три ошибки пришлось исправить, чтобы код запустился. Плюс нет кода, рисующего 4 графика в начале, а это тоже могло быть полезным для анализа.

Comment: @CrazyElf, спасибо за обратную связь. Буду внимательнее, поторопился!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Скорее всего тут вообще не нужно работать как с временными рядами. Но это нужно дополнительно проверять. На мой взгляд тут достаточно дня недели и времени суток:

```
import seaborn as sns

dt = pd.Series(df.index)
df['DayOfWeek'] = dt.dt.dayofweek.values
df['Hour'] = dt.dt.hour.values
df['Day'] = dt.dt.day.values

plt.figure()
sns.barplot(x = df.DayOfWeek, y = df.Registration)
plt.figure()
sns.barplot(x = df.Hour, y = df.Registration)
plt.figure()
sns.barplot(x = df.Day, y = df.Registration)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

День месяца кажется тоже сильной фичей, но я её потом выкинул, без неё лучше метрика получается. Слишком большой у неё разброс, он модель с толку сбивает в итоге.

```
from sklearn.metrics import mean_squared_error
from sklearn.ensemble import RandomForestRegressor

X = df.drop(columns=['Registration','Day'])
y = df['Registration']

train_size = 2 * df.shape[0] // 3

X_train = X[:train_size]
X_test = X[train_size:]
y_train = y[:train_size]
y_test = y[train_size:]

rf = RandomForestRegressor()
rf.fit(X_train, y_train)
y_preds = rf.predict(X_test)
print(mean_squared_error(y_test, y_preds))
print(rf.feature_importances_)

plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
sns.scatterplot(x=y_test.index, y = y_test.values)
sns.scatterplot(x=y_test.index, y = y_preds)

#19.04574056191149
#[0.35862722 0.64137278]
```

Сравниваем тестовую часть данных с предсказанием:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Результат не идеальный, но на что-то похож реальное.

P.S. Разброс отклонения предсказаний от теста. Видно, что модель завышает результат. Возможно, это как-раз связано с сезонностью (лето). Но без данных за несколько лет такую сезонность нельзя выделить из данных.

```
plt.figure(figsize=(16,8))
sns.scatterplot(x=y_test.index, y = y_preds - y_test.values, alpha=0.5)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Посмотрел, да, сезонность в зависимости от времени года явно есть. Либо это может быть связано с тем, что регистрации просто падают со временем. Сказать на основе данных меньше чем за год сложно.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: спасибо огромное. Я попробовал CatBoost-ом, результат лучше.

Comment: @Egor_1811 Ну дальше там можно ещё модели повыбирать и потюнить, Можно и с фичами что-то придумать - например, праздники прикрутить, возможно они тоже как-то влияют на целевую переменную. Не забудьте только обязательно учиться на данных до некоего момента, а проверять на данных после этого момента. Если со временем что-то меняется, то валидация с учётом времени получения данных важна.